# Using praw to scrape a list of subreddits: "TypeError: 'Subreddit' object is not iterable"

Tags: python-3.x, praw

I'm using praw with Python 3 to scrape posts and comments from a list of subreddits. The code previously worked for 1 subreddit as well as for a list of [j] search terms in a list of [i] subreddits. I removed the list of search terms and just want it to iterate through the list of subreddits, but I keep getting "TypeError: 'Subreddit' object is not iterable. I don't understand what happened?

```
subs= ["sub1","sub2", "sub3", "sub4"]

commentsDict = {"comment_user": [], "comment_text":[], "comment_score":[], "comment_date":[] }
postsDict = {"post_title" : [], "post_score" : [], "post_comments_num":[], "post_date":[], \
                "post_user":[], "post_text":[], "post_id":[]}

for i in range(len(subs)):
    for submission in reddit.subreddit(subs[i]):
        submission.comment_sort = 'new'
        comments = list(submission.comments)
        for comments in submission.comments:
            postsDict["post_title"].append(submission.title)#title of post with comment
            postsDict["post_score"].append(submission.score)#upvotes-downvotes
            postsDict["post_text"].append(submission.selftext)#get body of post
            postsDict["post_id"].append(submission.id)#unique id address for post
            postsDict["post_user"].append(submission.author)  #user name of poster
            postsDict["post_comments_num"].append(submission.num_comments) #number of comments on post
            date = submission.created_utc                                  #create variable for date
            timestamp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(date)              #create variable to translate unix date 
            postsDict["post_date"].append(timestamp.strftime('%Y-%m-%D %H:%M:%S')) #extract date and add to dict
            for top_level_comment in submission.comments:                   #create loop for extracting comments
                if isinstance(top_level_comment, MoreComments):
                    continue
            submission.comments.replace_more(limit=None)                   #tell Praw to click more comments and get those too
            commentsDict["comment_user"].append(comments.author)              #get comment username
            commentsDict["comment_score"].append(comments.score)            #comment upvotes-downvotes
            date = comments.created                                         #same date as above but for comments
            timestamp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(date)
            commentsDict["comment_date"].append(timestamp.strftime('%Y-%m-%D %H:%M:%S')) #add translated unix date to dict
            commentsDict["comment_text"].append(comments.body)      #get comment text
```

Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `subreddit.stream.submissions()` as a generator in your for loop.
e.g.

```
sub = reddit.subreddit(subreddit_name)
for submissions in sub.stream.submission():
    # Do stuff with submissions
```

Comment: Hi @tiega, this is incorrect because streams are designed for processing new submissions as they come in, and they will loop forever (without a `break`). This means that the code in the post will never be able to process more than the first subreddit.

Answer (score 0):

First of all (unrelated to your problem), this loop iterates through indices into the list `subs` and then uses that index to get an item:

```
for i in range(len(subs)):
    for submission in reddit.subreddit(subs[i]):
```

Change that to directly iterating over the subreddits:

```
for subreddit in subs:
    for submission in reddit.subreddit(subreddit):
```

And now to fix your PRAW mistake: you can't just iterate over a subreddit (`for submission in reddit.subreddit(subreddit)`). You have to specify what listing you want to iterate over (such as new, hot, or top). You can see a list of available listings in [the PRAW documentation for `Subreddit`](https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code_overview/models/subreddit.html). These listings correspond to the various tabs you'd see when viewing a subreddit on the web:

[image: Reddit tabs: hot, new, rising, controversial, top, gilded]

For example, using the [`hot` listing](https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code_overview/models/subreddit.html#praw.models.Subreddit.hot):

```
for subreddit in subs:
    for submission in reddit.subreddit(subreddit).hot():
```

If you want to specify the number of posts you get back, you can use the `limit` parameter:

```
for subreddit in subs:
    for submission in reddit.subreddit(subreddit).hot(limit=5):
```

The code above will give you 5 submissions at most from each subreddit.

The rest of your code does some unorthodox things. I commented on one of them on [your previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61415483/keep-getting-attribute-error-using-praw-to-scrape-specific-search-term-in-subred), which is this:

```
comments = list(submission.comments)
for comments in submission.comments:
```

You set `comments` equal to something and then never use it, because it is redefined on the next line. I would remove the `comments =` line, because it is doing nothing.

Also, for each comment in the post, you iterate through all the comments in the post and do nothing:

```
for top_level_comment in submission.comments:                   #create loop for extracting comments
    if isinstance(top_level_comment, MoreComments):
        continue
```

I don't know what you want this code to do, but right now it does nothing besides waste time, so I'd remove that too.

Comment: Thank you again for your help Jarhill0. I added the ```            for top_level_comment in submission.comments:                   #create loop for extracting comments
                if isinstance(top_level_comment, MoreComments):
                    continue``` as a result of last comments issue. My goal is to scrape all the posts and comments in a given time frame. My understanding is that when Praw came to the "more comments" option in reddit (the part that I'd click if I were browsing manually) it got confused and errored out.  I apprecaite you patience, I am VERY new to this.

Comment: In that case, you should add `if isinstance(top_level_comment, MoreComments): continue` right below `for comment in submission.comments:`